# Do you have to use node.js for the webhook fulfillment?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have an app set up on Api.ai that uses a webhook for fulfillment. The webhook is just a Laravel PHP api running on Nginx that returns the JSON response. All of the google documentation mentions using Node.js. Will my app be rejected if I dont use Node.js for the fulfillment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Node.js is not required. The Node.js client library is a convenience so you don't have to deal with the JSON payload directly.

You are free to implement your webhook on any platform using any language to handle the incoming HTTP requests with their JSON payloads and provide the necessary JSON response.

Your app will not be rejected if you don't use Node.js for fulfillment.